# How to create a bot user for an organization in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, automation

**Background:** In GitLab it is possible to create bot users for [projects](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html#bot-users-for-projects) and for [groups](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/settings/group_access_tokens.html#bot-users-for-groups). A project bot can only access one project by using one access token and a group bot can only access the projects that reside in a particular group.

**Aim:** to automate certain processes in multiple projects that reside in various groups by using one access token.

**Question:** Would it be possible to create a bot for an organization as well?

**Note:** [a GitLab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/386439) has been created.